# Lost connection between two data centers

Tags: mongodb, partition

Currently I'm struggle with this question.

Given I have a MongoDB instance, splited as a replica set over two datacenters in europe (containing the primary) and the united states. Each datacenter contains every needed component (mongod, mongos, rcrs). Even the backend and frontend is split over the two datacenters.

What happens now, if the connection between europe and the united states is broken? Will the mongo instance in the us elect a new primary and continue operate on their own? And if  this is the case, what happens, if the connection between eu and us is fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It very much depends how you have set up your replica sets. If the connection is broken, the datacenter which can reach a majority first would have a primary elected. By that i meant if your datacenter in US has only 2 memebers and 3 members are in Europe and assuming it is only the network glitch and systems are not down in reality then Europe datacenter can reach majority as it has 3 members so the primary would then be there in Europe because the 2 remaining memebers would not have majority. Even if one in US becomes primary it would step down as soon as it would notice that it cannot reach the majority. It is always better to design the replica sets partition in a way that it always has a primary.

When the whole set is back then there are many things in play, like - newest data, priority, hidden members etc. If let's say the one in US has a priority but since it would not have the latest data it cannot become primary immediately. Only after it has synced up to the latest records then only it would become primary.

Hope this somewhat helps.

Comment: The interesting case for me is, if there are 3 remaining members in eu and 3 in us - so each of them could elect a new primary on their own. Then the two partitions could run for some time on their own and there are two masters for this timespan

Comment: For 6 members you need to have 4 in majority. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-architectures/. Also as member set would have even number of members you would need to have an arbiter to solve the election problems. Also your set can be left without no primary left elected, worst case scenario and you might need to consider reconfig of set. Please see - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/reconfigure-replica-set-with-unavailable-members/